# How to solve this error " when casting from a number less than infinity 1 " in C#

Tags: c#

I want to perform auto search in text box like google in c# but it gives error on line

```
...
txt_item_name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
...
```

Here is my Code:

```
private void frm_bill_entry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autosearch(DataCollection);          
    txt_item_name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection; // This line gives error 'invalid cast exception was unhandled c#'
}

private void autosearch(AutoCompleteStringCollection datacollection)
{             
        string sql = "select item_name from item_master";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);
        da.Dispose();[enter image description here][1]
        cmd.Dispose();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            datacollection.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }            
}
```

Comment: Your error is in the autosearch subroutine. And on another note, I believe you should have "autosearch" return the "datacollection" parameter in order to apply changes to "DataCollection".

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of that exception? From the code shown I cannot spot any error. Your `DataCollection` is an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` and you only added strings to it. So it would be interesting if the stack trace says something more about which cast could have been so invalid.